# Better way of getting segment length from triangle with offset and extension

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a triangle and line with an offset (T) and I'm trying to find the best way of getting the length of two line segments (X1 and X2).  The height (B), length (A) and (T) will be variable but will be known.
[Overall layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Xke.png)

For X2 I have broken it up into [two segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TSGm.png).  The "tan(atan... is to get the units to work as I'm dealing with length units and degrees units:
$$\frac {T}{sin(atan(B/A)}+\frac {T}{tan(atan(B/A)}$$

For X1 this is at the intersection of the [two offset lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXId6.png):
$${tan(atan(A/B)}*\left[ \frac {T}{sin(atan(B/A)}-T\right]$$

I'm limited to pretty basic [arithmetic/trigonometric functions](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Revit-Model/files/GUID-B37EA687-2BDF-4712-9951-2088B2A8E523-htm.html).

To get the above, I stepped through the dimensions by [drafting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJjNt.png) a known set of conditions and working backwards.  If there's a cleaner way of getting these segment lengths, I would certainly appreciate the knowledge.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! I got the same result for $X_2$. You can sort of simplify it into
$$X_2=\frac TB\left(\sqrt{A^2+B^2}+A\right).$$
For $X_1$, I think you made an error in your calculations. I found that $X_1=X_{2a}-X_{2b}$, so
$$X_1=\frac TB\left(\sqrt{A^2+B^2}-A\right).$$
I don't think there is any way to get simpler expressions of these two lengths.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I made an error in my above X1 and left out a parentheses: tan(atan(A / B)) * **(*(T / sin(atan(A / B))) - T**)*
X1= X2a-X2b --- Got that genius realization to work.
The other ones, I can't get to work. Where A=12, B=8, T=0.125 and using the above, I get X2=-0.013995.  For the second equation above labeled X2 (which I think is supposed to be X1) = 0.15267.  X2 should be .41284 and X1 = .03784.  Once again, thank you very much @Isaac Ren!

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I forgot to inverse the $\sin$ and $\tan$... I just corrected the expressions. I checked for your example, and it gives the right results.

Comment: No worries at all: Thank you very much for helping me out. Those elegant equations were beyond my skills to reverse engineer! Thank you again, those are fantastic ways of solving with just simple math.